# I am unable to install @angular/CLI package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/CLI@latest

**

```
log:
```

**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/CLI',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose npm-session 55687b55be7d98d3
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fCLI 2180ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/CLI@latest 404 Not Found: @angular/CLI@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: @angular/CLI@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
10 verbose cwd C:\Users\PURUSHOTHAM
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@angular/CLI" "-g"
13 verbose node v8.11.3
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code E404
16 error 404 Not Found: @angular/CLI@latest
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Learn [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: Try with: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have installed node and npm?

Comment: its lower case, `@angular/cli`, not `@angular/CLI`

Comment: Thank u it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm install -g @angular/cli` should do it. Copy and paste into your terminal.

EDIT: 
On windows you might want to start your terminal as administrator by right-clicking > `Run as Administrator`.

On Mac/Linux add `sudo` before.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Go to Node.js folder where it is installed (in my case it is installed in path `C:\Program Files\nodejs`).
- Now open cmd on the same path and type `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
- Then `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

It should work. Happy learning!